# How do I use php-fpm on RHEL 7.2?

Tags: rhel, php, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I've already asked this on Stack Overflow but received no response, so I'm trying my luck here.

I'm new to configuring Apache and I'm trying to optimize my Apache server. Reading through the documentation, I found that I should be using the **Event MPM** instead of the **Prefork MPM**. Everything was straight forward until this point as I only had to comment out Prefork and uncomment Event in **00-mpm.conf**. However, when I restarted Apache, I got the following error -

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 31 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf: Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Digging for some more information, I found out that **mod_php** should not be used with Event. So, I'm commented out **php_value** in **php.conf** and also commented out **LoadModule** in **10-php.conf**.

My webpages wouldn't load anymore and I realized that I should be using **php-fpm**. However, documentation regarding this is really unclear and I'm not sure how to use it. I tried this -

```
[root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx ~]# yum install php-fpm
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php70w-fpm.x86_64 0:7.0.4-1.w7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php70w-common(x86-64) = 7.0.4-1.w7 for package: php70w-fpm-7.0.4-1.w7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php70w-common.x86_64 0:7.0.4-1.w7 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php70w-common-7.0.4-1.w7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I'm not sure how to proceed and would really appreciate any help with this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When using PHP-FPM you have no `PHP` configuration in Apache other than the directives used to map the request for `PHP` files to the back end FPM service (`ProxyPass` or a `RewriteRule` with the `[P]` flag)

`php_value` is a directive implemented by `mod_php` and so can only be used in setups that use `mod_php` itself.

Check the PHP-FPM documentation for details on how to replicate this functionality.

Other than that you seem to have a `PHP` package version inconsistency that needs to be resolved first. It looks like and upgrade from php-fpm before v5.5 is not supported, so you'll need to either use the one you have currently installed or resolve the problem manually.